# How access a specific position in racket list

Tags: list, recursion, racket

I am having problems in getting the position of the list I want.
I am not sure is what to use to be able to get the value from the asked position. 
If it was python I could repeat (fist( rest n) as many time I wanted, but here is racket I am confused.

```
(check-expect (get-char "abcdefg" 0) #\a)
(check-expect (get-char "abcdefg" 3) #\d)
(check-expect (get-char "abcdefg" 20) #\*)
(define (list-of-char string-input)
  (string->list string-input))
(define (get-char string-input position)
  (cond [(empty? (list-of-char string-input)) #\*]
        [(> position (string-length string-input)) #\*]
        [else (cond
                [
                   [else (get-char (rest (list-of-char string-input)) position)])])
```

Comment: In Racket we also repeat `rest` a given amount of times, it's just that we use recursion to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several bugs in your code. For starters, you should decrease the position when advancing the recursion, and you should convert the string to a list only once, at the start.

Also, you're not correctly checking to see if you reached the expected position - the remaining length is not equivalent to the position you wish to find. And that `else/cond/else` part at the end doesn't make sense, and it has too many brackets.

A solution from scratch in Scheme would typically use a named `let` for the recursion, but I'll use a helper procedure for simplicity's sake:

```scm
(define (get-char string-input position)
  ; convert to a list only once at the beginning
  (loop (string->list string-input) position))

(define (loop list-of-char position)
        ; there are two exit conditions we need to check
  (cond [(or (empty? list-of-char)
             (negative? position)) #\*]
        ; we found the element
        [(zero? position) (first list-of-char)]
        ; keep looking
        [else (loop (rest list-of-char) (sub1 position))]))
```

And we can write a more idiomatic solution using built-in procedures:

```scm
(define (get-char string-input position)
  (if (or (negative? position)
          (>= position (string-length string-input)))
      #\*
      (string-ref string-input position)))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```scm
(get-char "abcdefg" -1)
; => #\*

(get-char "abcdefg" 0)
; => #\a

(get-char "abcdefg" 3)
; => #\d

(get-char "abcdefg" 6)
; => #\g

(get-char "abcdefg" 7)
; => #\*
```